# Laravel 5.4 - cannot set debug environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am taking the "Laravel 5.4 From Scratch' course on Laracasts. I created two projects and everything was working well, but I realized that the server stopped showing me debug errors. It now throws the generic 'Sorry, page could not be found' error in BOTH applications (completely separate from each other), I run them with `php artisan serve`.

Laravel is ignoring the `APP_DEBUG=true` and `APP_ENV=local` in `.env` file.

In `config/app.php`:

> 'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'local');
>
> 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true);

The application doesn't show debug, just some regular simple 'this page can not be found' errors.

I've tried:

- rebooting the server
- `php artisan config:clear`
- `php artisan optimize`
- `php artisan cache:clear`

nothing works, the environment is still production-like, doesn't display any errors.

How to turn on debugging?

UPDATE: `php artisan env` returns `local` but on the browser-side nothing changes, still generic user-friendly error pages. I tried on different browsers and clearing browser cache, nothing works.

Comment: Are you getting 404 error from laravel application? or is request is not hitting application itself?

Comment: @JithinJose The request is hitting the application, and then the application returns nicely rendered page saying "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: @JithinJose UPDATE: `php artisan env` returns `local` but on the browser-side nothing changes, still generic user-friendly error pages. I tried on different browsers and clearing browser cache, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The error you mention is a 404, not an error when the app fails, so the error has not much to say.

Try writting some breaking code to see the detailed debugging error

If both apps started to show that error in well-known routes you had working before, maybe you modified something that breaked all the routes and you cannot match any of them.

Comment: This is not a debug - type error. But to be sure I removed the CSRF token from a form and submitted the data. Instead of an error with a stack trace giving me information about mismatched tokens, all I got was a nice looking page saying 'The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again.'

Comment: Yeah, that error is also normal, because of the token. Try to use some inexistent variable in a controller and hit that route.

Comment: those errors that I am now receiving are NOT what the usual error looks like. There is no stack trace, there is no information about the error, the debug is nowhere to be found.

Comment: This is what I SHOULD get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g5ui.png but instead I get blank white page with some user friendly message in the middle

Comment: Try with a `dd(config('app.debug'))` in a controller method to see what the current debug status is

Comment: Returns true. Still only generic user friendly messages. I have bootstrap in my application if that matters.

Comment: Does application have custom exception handler which is not respecting app.debug?

Comment: I tried echoing a non-existent variable and the debugger worked, but then why didn't it work on CSRF token mismatch? I am watching the Laracasts video and the tutor had the detailed version of the error in the same situation, but for some reason I get the non-verbose version...

Comment: @JithinJose no, it is just a brand-new Laravel application with some blogging code on top of it. I just started learning Laravel and did not make it to custom exception handlers yet.

Comment: Check if you have this property in env file `APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug` and if not, add it. Maybe it helps on showing errors on screen

Comment: @Lloople `APP_LOG_LEVEL` is set to debug in env file.